# How I can compare 2 files without download then by using PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I have 1 image (source) stored in one server (this server is only an data server without php or anything), using gd I create another image in a php server with the source as base for creation, so I have one generated image and one source file, for performance I create some kind of a "cache" script thats make a copy of my generated image  in my php server, the question is how I can compare if the source image have been update to update my cache? (without using a database, just files treatment, and I need speed and low bandwidth use)

the "cache simple code" is:

```
<?php           
if (!file_exists('cache_image.png')) {
        $img = file_get_contents('image_generator.png');
        file_put_contents('cache_image.png',$img);

}else{
//i need to test if the source image have been updated

}

?>
```

Comment: If you want to check if a file has been changed, can't you just check the modification time?

Comment: Create two `img` tags, one for each image, put the text "Are these images the same?" and a "Yes" button and a "No" button on the page, and let the user tell you.

Comment: i'm trying to check modification time, as suggested @derobert, but im having some troubles to get the modification time of an external file

Comment: @LuanCitta: "External file"? If its on a filesystem mounted on the local machine, `stat` will give you that info. If its on a web server, make a HEAD request and check the response Last-Modified time. (Of course, you probably want to think twice before implementing your own web cache; have you looked at apache's? Or squid?)

Comment: @derobert - I said "Cache", but in reality it is not. only conceptually actually, because I keep the image generated on my server to avoid to make it again and again unnecessarily, you know?

Comment: @LuanCitta: Well, then telling if it is outdated is going to require knowing the age of the data it was generated from, how much lag is acceptable, etc. And yes, that's a cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a MD5 hash of each file and compare the hashes.

Comment: This would require downloading entire files.

Comment: when i compare those 2 files i have speed problems, because the time of generating external files md5 is to long and i have to display about 120 images each time...

Comment: When and how is the file updated on the other server? Might it be possible to create a file on the server with the times that the files were updated and then just parse that file?

Comment: OR create a .sh script on the data server.
This .sh script will be passed the file names and return the modification date of each.

You can then call this file at th beginning of your php script.

I realize you said the data server doesn't have PHP or "anything" but I have never known a data server to not have bash/ksh or something on it. =)